# Refactoring methods that use the same code but different input params

Tags: java, refactoring, code-cleanup

I have these two methods. Can someone help me to refactor and make them common?

```
public void method1(Map<String,String> map, String key, String value){
  map.put(key, value);
}

public void method2(GenericRecord recordMap, String key, String value){
  recordMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Unable to refactor it.

Comment: Make `GenericRecord` implement `Map`. Otherwise, you can't. Java has no duck typing.

Comment: @Michael not entirely true. We could define an interface `KeyValueConsumer<K, V>` with a method `void consume(K key, V value)` and then require a `KeyValueConsumer<String, String>`as parameter, that can be passed along as a lambda.

Comment: @Turing85 And in the context of this contrived example, you just invented a method that does almost nothing. The one single thing these methods do is call `put`, and you just shifted that responsibility to the caller.

Comment: @Michael depending on the content of the actual method, it centralizes the implementation.

Comment: @Turing85 It's not worth speculating about that. We simply don't know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the [`BiConsumer` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html). We can use this interface to implement the `put`-logic we need:

```
static <K, V> void add(BiConsumer<K, V> consumer, K key, V value) {
  consumer.accept(key, value);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
add(map::put, key, value);
add(record::put, key, value);
```

If we want, we can define overloaded convenience-methods:

```
static <K, V> void add(Map<K, V> map, K key, V value) {
  add(map::put, key, value);
}

static <K, V> void add(GenericRecord<K, V> record, K key, V value) {
  add(record::put, key, value);
}
```

and just call the methods as we do now.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CoqvJb)